# issues with data received from api,data maybe a string or null

Tags: flutter, api, dart

i'am using tmdb to fetch movies data,all things work alright till a try to fetch movies from the third page of popular movies,
here is the error i got

> Exception occured: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' stackTrace: #0

this is the fetch function witch return the error:

```
class DioApiClient implements ApiClient {
  final Dio dio = Dio();
  final Api api = Api();

  @override
  Future<List<MovieModel>> getDataFrom(String endPoint,
      {Map<String, dynamic>? params}) async {
    final String url = "${api.baseURL}/$endPoint";
    log("from api client :$url/$params");

    Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters = {
      'api_key': api.apiKey,
      // 'language': 'en-US',
    };
    if (params != null) {
      queryParameters.addAll(params);
    }

    try {
      final response = await dio.get(url, queryParameters: queryParameters);

      log(" status code : ${response.statusCode}");
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = response.data;
        final List<dynamic> results = data['results'];
        final List<MovieModel> movies =
            results.map((dynamic movie) => MovieModel.fromJson(movie)).toList();

        return movies;
      }

      
    } catch (error, stacktrace) {
      log("Exception occured: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
      throw Exception('Failed to load data ');
    }
    throw Exception("data not found");
  }
}
```

and here is the movie model:

```
import '../../domain/entities/movie_entity.dart';

class MovieModel {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String overview;
  final String posterPath;
  final num voteAverage;
  final String backdropPath;
  final String releaseDate;

  MovieModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.overview,
    required this.posterPath,
    required this.voteAverage,
    required this.backdropPath,
    required this.releaseDate,
  });

  factory MovieModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MovieModel(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      overview: json['overview'],
      posterPath: json['poster_path'],
      voteAverage: json['vote_average'],
      backdropPath: json['backdrop_path'],
      releaseDate: json['release_date'],
    );
  }

  MovieEntity toEntity() {
    return MovieEntity(
      id: id,
      title: title,
      overview: overview,
      posterPath: posterPath,
      voteAverage: voteAverage,
      backdropPath: backdropPath,
      releaseDate: releaseDate,
    );
  }
}
```

i tried to make the backdropPath and posterPath nullable but its the i got same behavior
[image: API RESPONSE]

Comment: Hi @Ydev, as error indicate itself, you need to find which data is coming null from api   that should be any of String type object from your MovieModel.

Comment: yeah there is two fields witch can be a string or null ,'backdropPath' and 'posterPath'

Comment: try to replace  final Map<String, dynamic> data to Map<dynamic, dynamic> , because there might be a case that any key is null and that may also cause issue. I will recommend you to run app in debug mode and try to run debugger step by step with breakpoint's

Comment: not the probleme ,i think the probleme is in the fromJson function when fetching data from the api,because there is some null filds in the the response body for some movies page only otherwise all work fine for all other pages page and categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json can have null values (as you have shown in your screen poster_path and backdrop_path).

This means the `posterPath: json['poster_path']` will crash if it is null, because you try to set a null value inside a non-nullable String. You either make your string nullable or you do a safety check. It's a good practice to set default values if your value is null, like this:

```
posterPath: json['poster_path'] != null ? json['poster_path'] : "",
```

or you use the short variation with the ?? operator:

```
  posterPath: json['poster_path'] ?? "",
```

Your fromJson can look like this:

```
return MovieModel(
      id: json['id'] ?? 0,
      title: json['title'] ?? "",
      overview: json['overview'] ?? "",
      posterPath: json['poster_path'] ?? "",
      voteAverage: json['vote_average'] ?? 0,
      backdropPath: json['backdrop_path'] ?? "",
      releaseDate: json['release_date'] ?? "",
    );
```